# Increased Docker memory size and now docker compose wont work

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I increased my docker for windows CPU and memory size in settings, and it did a restart, then I tried to run `docker-compose up -d` on my project and I got the following error `ERROR: Named volume "C:/Users/andersk/sites/sylr:/var/www/html" is used in service "wordpress" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

Here is my docker compose file, it was working just fine up until I increased those settings in the docker.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "2000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes: 
       - C:/Users/andersk/sites/sylr:/var/www/html
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Comment: Are you using docker-compose from CMD or WSL? And didn't you accidentally also update docker-compose? What version are you using?

Comment: Buddy you need to declare the volume in your volume section

Comment: I am such an idiot I was running it under wsl and was supposed to be in powershell

Comment: @AndersKitson it may run in wsl however you'll need to change your path to `/mnt/c/Users/Andersk/sites/sylr:/var/www/html` or use a relative path. Another option would be to create a docker volume container, and link it as @varnit says

Comment: Should I just delete this question I don't see this helping anyone, maybe it will

Comment: Right @baklap4 docker named volume can be used in place

Comment: Let me add the answer with named volume it might help someone i found on github people are struggling with named volume problem

Comment: @AndersKitson the question isn't particularly bad, but IMHO a lot of answers is, missing the point. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ran from WSL one can change your `docker-compose.yml` to the following

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "2000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes: 
       - /mnt/c/Users/andersk/sites/sylr:/var/www/html
```

Note the prefix `/mnt/c` instead of `C:/`

Another method would be to use a relative path or create a named volume like:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "2000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes: 
       - some_volume_name:/var/www/html
volumes: 
   some_volume_name: {}
```

If ran from Powershell it should work just out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker named volume in place and share that name across multiple containers, it would also make debugging easier

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
  backup:
    image: backup-service
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/backup/data

volumes:
  data-volume:
```